# Creation of table in oracle db using codeigniter DB forge class

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, dbforge

I am new to this community. May be this is a simple question but i have no idea how to create a new table in oracle using codeigniter dbforge class. I have tried with following code:

```
$this->load->dbforge(); 
$fields = array(
                'ORG_ID' => array(
                    'type' => 'INT',
                    'constraint' => 11,
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,
                    'auto_increment' => TRUE
                ),
                'NAME' => array(
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => '255'
                )
            ); 
            $this->dbforge->add_field($fields); // Add fields to table 
            echo "after field";
            $this->dbforge->add_key('ORG_ID', TRUE); // gives PRIMARY KEY (ORG_ID) 
            echo "after key";
            $this->dbforge->create_table('ORGANIZATION',TRUE);
            echo "last";
```

It is not executing the following line

```
$this->dbforge->create_table('ORGANIZATION',TRUE);
```

But it is not displaying any error and just getting following output:

```
Inside functionafter fieldafter key
```

Can any one suggest me that this is the correct way of creating tables in oracle using CI dbforge class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 8 months and almost 100 views and no answer? My dislike for Oracle is growing by the day.